# Unable to finish activity when click back button

Tags: android

I used below code to close activity after back button pressed.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
       super.onBackPressed();
       finish();
   }
```

after 5 time pressed it worked

how to solve it ?

Comment: Can you share more code? There must something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: it is default behavior anyway, why you even want to override it then?

Comment: Are any fragments involved in this process? Does the back stack have more than one, instances of your activity?

Comment: add you activity class code

Answer (score 0):

remove `super.onBackPressed();` to avoid handling the back button by the class parents

Answer (score 0):

If you want to finish when back press. don't need to Override.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
         // do something
    }
```

this will do nothing when you press back button. 
onBackPressed() usually needed when you want make custom ask to close dialog when back press.